# Font management between machines/OS

Tags: text-object, font

Is there a way to make Text objects reference fonts via a relative path?

I have my .blend file versioned, and it will be used on other machines. To make fonts consistent, I would also add a `fonts/` folder to the versioning system.

Ideally, all .blend files would point to these font files, so no matter where they are opened the same fonts would be available.

Also, is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Just a wild idea: why don't you simply test if it works? I downloaded a free font (to make it's one I haven't installed in my system), saved a file with a text in a specific folder. In this folder I created a subfolder "font" and placed the font in there, then I went to the _Text Properties_, chose the font from this subfolder and saved the file. Then I moved everything to a USB stick, opened the file from there and the text had the correct font. Easy as that. When the font is not present in the folder, the text uses the default font (but shows the name in the _Text Properties_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender has the ability to encapsulate (incorporate) various kinds of data (including fonts) within the blend-file that is normally saved outside of the blend-file. This allows sharing a full project as a single file, instead of e.g. an archive containing the blend-file and all its dependencies.

To pack external resources, click: File ‣ External Data ‣ Pack Resources

You know that a data is packed when you see a little “gift box” icon displayed next to its name:

[image]

If you want to keep the font "separate" in case of tracking by svn, you can ensure that your paths are relative by clicking: File ‣ External Data ‣ Make Paths Relative

Comment: That's what I suggest for a single file as well. But the font folder version is also a good option if you maybe want to share multiple files that should all have access to the same font, so you don't have to pack the font in each blend file. //EDIT: Oh, you edited your answer ;)